# Careers 2.0 navigation and filter problem, no bookmark support for list filter

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, navigation

In the job listing page after applying a filter the url does not change, this makes it impossible to bookmark the page. Another issue is after selecting a job from the list it navigates to the job details page and again the url does not change, this makes it impossible to go back and keep the filter. I know this is because its loading asynchronously but at least it should add an hash to the url with the job id and applied filter.

Comment: What browser are you using? It works for me in Chrome 30.

Comment: I'm also using the latest chrome 30. Click Seach jobs, it gets this address http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs and never changes to the filter or job details

Comment: If you do a search on the initial page it changes the url to this http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=node&location=london which is ok. But again if you navigate back, the textboxes have the filter but the list is not filtered.